# MySQL, replacing &nbsp; with... nothing (delete those, please!)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, replace

I'm trying to purge my WordPress content from "false" carriage return (CR). These are caused after a migration of my content, that **now presents from time to time a `&nbsp;` code** that makes the web rendering engine to "paint" a CR where I would like to be nothing. The paragraphs seem to have a double CR because of this, and look too far apart.

I'd like to be able to make a MySQL query in order to get rid of that strings, but at the moment I haven't found the key. What I've tried is

```
UPDATE wp_posts set post_content = replace (post_content,'&nbsp;',' ');
```

But i get

```
<p> </p>
```

where before were the `&nbsp;` strings. This seems not the answer at all. Could it have to be with the ampersand, and in that case, should I use something like `&amp;nbsp;` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why `&nbsp;` would be interpreted as a carriage return, because it should look like a space (Non-Breaking SPace).  In any case, I was able to get your SQL to work on a test database I created by changing the string to have double-quotes.

`UPDATE wp_posts set post_content = replace (post_content,"&nbsp;","");`

Also note, there is no space between the last pair.  You want it to replace `&nbsp;` with nothing, not a space.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but din't work :( The double quotes didn't change the DB, although you're right: I want to replace that with nothing. When I try your idea, I get this: `mysql> UPDATE wp_posts set post_content = replace (post_content,"&nbsp;","");
Query OK, 7 rows affected (1.34 sec)
Rows matched: 15232  Changed: 7  Warnings: 0`

Answer (score 1):

The code `<p>&nbsp;</p>` is frequently used by some GUI HTML editors to represent a carriage return.  I would be that what you really need to be searching for and removing is `<p>&nbsp;</p>`, and not just `&nbsp;` which is just a [non-breaking space character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

Comment: Unfortunately, no changes either with that idea. But it should have made a difference: `mysql> UPDATE wp_posts set post_content = replace (post_content,"<p>&nbsp;</p>","");
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.26 sec)
Rows matched: 15232  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0`

Comment: Aaah...I wasn't thinking about the nbsp wrapped in the <P> tags for a CR.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You now might have cases with `<p></p>` since you've replaced the `&nbsp;`s with empty strings.